# AngularJS UI to have the fields in each line and not side by side

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I am new to the angular and not able to tweak the UI  have the input boxes appear in the top down instead of side by side manner. Below is the html and it looks like

[image]

```
 <div>
   <form name="homeForm">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 md-padding">
        <div>
            <label style="font-size: medium">Laboratory Name</label>
            <select name="labName" class="form-control" ng-model="request.labName" required>
                <option ng-repeat="lab in labList" value="{{lab.id}}">{{lab.value}}</option>
            </select>
            <div style="color:maroon" ng-messages="homeForm.labName.$error"
                 ng-if="homeForm.labName.$touched">
                <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div >
            <label style="font-size: medium">Request Type</label>
            <select name="requestTypeName" class="form-control" ng-model="request.requestType" required>
                <option ng-repeat="requestType in reqTypeList" value="{{requestType.value}}">{{requestType.value}}</option>
            </select>
            <div style="color:maroon" ng-messages="homeForm.requestTypeName.$error"
                 ng-if="homeForm.requestTypeName.$touched">
                <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label style="font-size: medium">From Date (yyyy-mm-dd)</label>
            <p class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                       id="fromDate"
                       name="fromDate"
                       uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                       ng-model="request.fromDate"
                       is-open="popup1.opened"
                       datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                       ng-required="true"
                       close-text="Close"
                       alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"
                       required />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                    </span>
            </p>
            <div style="color:maroon" ng-messages="homeForm.fromDate.$error"
                 ng-if="homeForm.fromDate.$touched">
                <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label style="font-size: medium">To Date (yyyy-mm-dd)</label>
            <p class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                       id="toDate"
                       name="toDate"
                       uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                       ng-model="request.toDate"
                       is-open="popup2.opened"
                       datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                       ng-required="true"
                       close-text="Close"
                       alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"
                       required />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                </span>
            </p>
            <div style="color:maroon" ng-messages="homeForm.toDate.$error"
                 ng-if="homeForm.toDate.$touched">
                <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="md-padding col-md-6">
            <div class="row form-group">
                <button type="button" class='btn btn-danger' ng-click="clearRequest(homeForm)">Clear</button>
                <!--ng-disabled="!homeForm.$valid" -->
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="Views/Angular/results.html" ng-disabled="!homeForm.$valid" ng-click="createRequest(homeForm)">Submit</button>
                <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="createRequest(homeForm)">Submit</button> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </form>
 </div>
```

I am not able to make the From Date field and the To date field appear top down. I even tried putting `<p></p>` tags in between the both the fields but it is not working.

Comment: Please, provide us with a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example if possible. A JSFiddle would be handy right now.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should remove the bootstrap class "col-md-6" from your datepicker div. If needed you can assign col-md-6 class to div containing input-group.

```
<div>
   <form name="homeForm">
     <div class="form-group col-md-6 md-padding">
       <div>
        <label style="font-size: medium">Laboratory Name</label>
        <select name="labName" class="form-control" ng-model="request.labName" required>
            <option ng-repeat="lab in labList" value="{{lab.id}}">{{lab.value}} 
            </option>
        </select>
        <div style="color:maroon" ng-messages="homeForm.labName.$error"
             ng-if="homeForm.labName.$touched">
            <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div >
        <label style="font-size: medium">Request Type</label>
        <select name="requestTypeName" class="form-control" ng-model="request.requestType" required>
            <option ng-repeat="requestType in reqTypeList" value="{{requestType.value}}">{{requestType.value}}</option>
        </select>
        <div style="color:maroon" ng-messages="homeForm.requestTypeName.$error"
             ng-if="homeForm.requestTypeName.$touched">
            <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label style="font-size: medium">From Date (yyyy-mm-dd)</label>
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                   id="fromDate"
                   name="fromDate"
                   uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                   ng-model="request.fromDate"
                   is-open="popup1.opened"
                   datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                   ng-required="true"
                   close-text="Close"
                   alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"
                   required />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                </span>
        </p>
        <div style="color:maroon" ng-messages="homeForm.fromDate.$error"
             ng-if="homeForm.fromDate.$touched">
            <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label style="font-size: medium">To Date (yyyy-mm-dd)</label>
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                   id="toDate"
                   name="toDate"
                   uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                   ng-model="request.toDate"
                   is-open="popup2.opened"
                   datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                   ng-required="true"
                   close-text="Close"
                   alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"
                   required />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </p>
        <div style="color:maroon" ng-messages="homeForm.toDate.$error"
             ng-if="homeForm.toDate.$touched">
            <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="md-padding col-md-6">
        <div class="row form-group">
            <button type="button" class='btn btn-danger' ng-click="clearRequest(homeForm)">Clear</button>
            <!--ng-disabled="!homeForm.$valid" -->
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="Views/Angular/results.html" ng-disabled="!homeForm.$valid" ng-click="createRequest(homeForm)">Submit</button>
            <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="createRequest(homeForm)">Submit</button> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```